# Image resizing in C# with alignment of a logo and text in the image to the top

Tags: c#

I have an image 3519 X 2495 with some logo and text next to it. When the image is opened, i see the logo and the text next to it in the center. I would like to resize the image to 768 X 1004 and want both the logo and the text next to it to appear on the top. When I resize the image I get the logo and text next to it in the center.

Is there a good way to achieve this in c#.

I tried the below code

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(@"D:\SSH\Automation\ImageResize\Diageo.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(768, 1004);

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 768, 1004);
bitmap.Save(@"D:\SSH\Automation\ImageResize\Diageo.png");
graphics.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize an image and keep its initial aspect ratio use the following code:

Note that I use `using`s from the `IDisposable` interface instead of calling `Dispose` myself as this is considered best practice and is safer.

```
int maxWidth = 768;
int maxHeight = 1004;

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(filePath))
{
    int width = (int)(bitmap.Width * (maxHeight / (float)bitmap.Height));
    int height = maxHeight;

    if (bitmap.Height * (maxWidth / (float)bitmap.Width) <= maxHeight)
    {
        width = maxWidth;
        height = (int)(bitmap.Height * (maxWidth / (float)bitmap.Width));
    }

    using (Bitmap resizedBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        resizedBitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(resizedBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height);
        }

        //Use resizedBitmap here
    }
}
```